# Cómo cambiar el tema de Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto, un sitio web y tengo un mapa oscuro de Google Maps, que es un mapa común con una coordenada especifica la latitud y la longitud, pero me gustaría que **el tema** del mapa sea dinámico, por ejemplo, el tema azul con la posibilidad de utilizar la función de vista calle de Google Streetview con el mapa de control de zoom en el lado, tengo este código:

```js
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.385873, -1.471471),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    styles: [{
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 29
        }, {
            "weight": 0.2
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 18
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 16
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 21
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }, {
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 16
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 36
        }, {
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 40
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 19
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#000000"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }, {
            "weight": 1.2
        }]
    }]
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
```

```css
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Google Maps API Key - You will need to use your own API key to use the map feature -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

 <!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahora mismo el mapa se ve oscuro porque tienes definidos estilos propios con color negro y diferentes niveles de claridad para los diferentes elementos del mapa. Para que se vea azul, en lugar de indicar el color como `#000000`, dale un valor que sea una tonalidad de azul (por ejemplo `#3020dd`).

Ahora, para añadir controles de zoom al mapa y permitir la opción de Google Street View, el procedimiento va a ser similar. Como se indica en la [documentación de Google Maps sobre controles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls), puedes especificar qué controles quieres indicando un valor booleano:

- `zoomControl`: controles de zoom
- `mapTypeControl`: controles de tipo de mapa
- `scaleControl`: control de escala (la barra que muestra a qué escala está el mapa)
- `streetViewControl`: controles para permitir Google Street View
- `rotateControl`: controles para permitir la rotación del mapa
- `fullscreenControl`: controles para poner el mapa en modo pantalla completa

En tu caso sería el zoom y Google Street View, por lo que tienes que añadir:

```
zoomControl: true,
streetViewControl: true,
```

Y en esa misma página, te indica cómo posicionar los controles dentro del mapa, en tu caso sería algo como esto (para ponerlos en la esquina superior izquierda):

```
zoomControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
},
streetViewControlOptions: {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
},
```

Así quedaría el código con esos cambios:

```js
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.385873, -1.471471),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },
    styles: [{
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 29
        }, {
            "weight": 0.2
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 18
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 16
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 21
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }, {
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 16
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 36
        }, {
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 40
        }]
    }, {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 19
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#3020dd"
        }, {
            "lightness": 17
        }, {
            "weight": 1.2
        }]
    }]
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
```

```css
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Google Maps API Key - You will need to use your own API key to use the map feature -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

 <!-- Core JavaScript Files -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
```